# Framework for mobile/cloud synchronizing

Tags: android, google-app-engine, synchronization, cloud

I want to write an application that receives some data from the cloud. Additionally the data should be accessable, when the user is offline, which means I have to store it locally (sqlite or smth. similar).

Last week I read about [CouchDB Mobile](http://www.couchbase.com/mobile). This would be my solution if I would use a couchdb as online storage. But I don't want to use couchdb as online storage. Instead I am using Objectify in an appengine environment.

Is there a framework, which stores requested data local and checks for updates automatically? Or do I have to write that by my own?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of such framework that keeps a local copy of remotely accessed data from Datastore.

You could use the App Engine Java remote_api in conjuction with sqlite to keep a copy of the data locally and safe among app switches.

On the other hand that could raise an issue of consistency if the data kept locally has been modified by someone else in Datastore.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing that I'm aware of.

Android has sync adapters, but that is just one piece - not an equivelent of what CouchDB does:
http://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/index.html

The new 'google cloud save' feature of play services, which is currently in closed beta, sounds like it could develop in that direction - currently it just makes saving/loading from datastore simple.
https://developer.android.com/google/gcs/index.html

And I don't think there is a silver bullet anyway.  A framework can do a lot for you on the client, but sync'ing logic is not generic on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out, i think titanium have an api to handle data sync.
http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/Alloy_Sync_Adapters_and_Migrations

Comment: Links can become invalid and then your answer contains no information anymore.
You should summarize the solution, that can be found on the link, here in your answer and add the link only for addional information.